# How to share model object between view controllers?

Tags: xcode, swift, macos, cocoa

I created a basic **OS X** application with a storyboard to just draw circles in a custom view. The main window contains a `NSSplitViewController`containing two sub-views (content and side bar like Apple Pages or Numbers have). The content view is a custom subclass of `NSView` for drawing circles while the side bar view contains standard controls. Both should be bound to a model object which holds the properties like number of circles, diameter and so on.

As I understand both subviews have their own controllers in any case. How do have a data model object (let's call it `Circles`) which both controllers reference so I can hook up key-value observation for redrawing my custom view on changing the controls' values?

My idea would be to create the model object in the common parent controller and pass it on to the children, but how to set that up in Interface Builder in Xcode 7.2?

Comment: You can pass it along to the representedObject for each child view controller and just observe that, or you can always make your own property and observe it there. Not sure why this has to necessarily be done in IB?

Comment: @LucasDerraugh Thanks, I did not know about `representedObject` yet. [In my `SplitViewController`](https://github.com/alomvar/circleception/blob/master/Circleception/SplitViewController.swift) I set the `representedObject` property of child controllers. Would you mind posting it as an answer (I would accept)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working off my comment. You can use the `representedObject` property of NSViewController to pass any object along to other view controllers. The one downside to this though is that the property is of type `AnyObject?` so making that work with Swift can be awkward. In your NSViewController subclass you can make a new property to store the data and give it the correct type, or you could make a protocol to define the computed property that serves as a wrapper around `representedObject` property.